# Http Client 4.5 not reusing the same connection using pooling connection manager in java

Tags: java, tcp

My below code is using pooling connection manager of apache http client 4.5 version. If I make a 50 requests, I am seeing in netstat 50 different tcp ports are being used, but at max using 5 connections alive any time. I have seen in wire shark also having filter `tcp.flags.syn==1 && tcp.flags.ack==0` it is creating 50 packets in filter, so it is using different connections rather than using the same connection, so why am not able to do?

my code:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.config.Registry;
import org.apache.http.config.RegistryBuilder;
import org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.ConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.glassfish.jersey.SslConfigurator;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class App3Conn {
    private static CloseableHttpClient client;


    static String target="https://example.com";

    static PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm ;
static{

SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance()
            .securityProtocol("TLS")
            .keyStoreFile("/Users/file")
            .keyStorePassword("passw")
            .keyStoreType("JKS")
            .trustStoreFile("/Users/file");

    SSLContext sslCtx = sslConfig.createSSLContext();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslCtx,NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> r = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
            .register("https", sslsf)
            .build();


    cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(r);
    cm.setMaxTotal(15);
    cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(5);

    client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).setConnectionManager(cm).build();


}
public static void main(String a[]) throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException, IOException
{

    JSONObject jsonMessage = new JSONObject();



    JSONObject jsonResponse;

    jsonMessage.put("keyID", "keyID" );


     StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonMessage.toString());
     CloseableHttpResponse response2;
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(target);
    httpPost.setEntity(se);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    {

        response2 = client.execute(httpPost);


     HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
     String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity2);

     EntityUtils.consume(entity2);


     jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);

    String text = jsonResponse.getString("result");


    response2.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Might be related to your TLS configuration. I suspect it thinks it needs a new connection every time and doesn't realize it can reuse the connection.  Maybe try if removing that fixes the symptom with some different server. If so, the SSLConnectionSocketFactory might be the problem. I don't actually use that myself so can't help you any further.

Comment: Check which side is closing the connection and what the HTTP headers say. Keep-Alive is just a proposal of the client and not a must for the server. The server can still close the connection after the request is done.

Comment: server is having 24 hours of keep alive property

Comment: so if  i run same code for fb.com in a get request using pooling connection manager and removing the sslconfigarator,sslcontext,sslsocket factory i build client using only connection pooling manager and no registery for connection pooling manager it is working fine

Answer (score 9):

I've seen this one before. It was down to the way that the Apache connection pool works. An opaque `state` member is associated with the pool entry and must match to the requested state when a pool entry is requested (leased).

When a connection lease attempt is made the `state` requested is `null`. However when the connection is put back into the pool the `state` is set to the `X500Principal` object of the SSL peer. This happens in the `DefaultUserTokenHandler` class. Luckily this is overridable when we create the `HttpClient` class. Here's an example:

```
HttpClient apacheHttpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setConnectionReuseStrategy(new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy())
    .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(r))
    .setUserTokenHandler(new UserTokenHandler() {
      @Override
      public Object getUserToken(HttpContext context) {
        return null;
      }
    })
    .build();
```

Do check that you're not losing anything that you depend on from `DefaultUserTokenHandler` and don't use this method if the `HttpClient` that you create can connect to multiple SSL peers through the same HTTP route. In my case this client is used to connect to a single SSL server.